# Unity trying to scale UI when mouse is over

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to scale a UI when mouse is over the UI but in my code, when mouse is over a UI, all the UI elements are scaling and I only to scale the UI that my mouse is over. Here's my code:

```
public void StartScale(){
    foreach (GameObject button in buttons){
        LeanTween.scale(button, new Vector2(scaleAmount, scaleAmount), scaleSpeed);
    }
}
```

I have an array of game objects that I want to scale. I want them to scale only when my mouse is over but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things at play here. One is how you populate your buttons list, no information was provided for us to work with. The other is the transform hierarchy. If you scale an object, anything that is a child will also scale as all transformations are relative to the parent.

In this case my suspicion is that you've accidentally added an object too far up your hierarchy tree to the list, or have made certian GameObjects children of the object you intended to scale.

Comment: I don't really understand what is adding an object too far up my hierarchy tree to the list. Can you explain to me ? Thank you

Comment: I mean if you have a bunch of GameObjects connected as a child of another then if you scale the parent then all of the children will also scale.

It's possible you have added a GameObject with children to the buttons list and are getting unwanted behaviour as a result.

Comment: Does a button with a text children counts(It's kind of obvious that a button has a text children I think)? Otherwise I don't have a GameObject with children in the button list. I also think that it's a problem with my code because in my code, when my mouse is over a button, I scale them all (foreach button of buttons). I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Yes those are normal to have as children. Is your issue that you only want the button you moused over to scale? If so then why are you scaling everything in that list? It seems like the very intention of the code you pasted is to scale all the buttons. 

You'll need to get a reference to the button under the mouse and only run the scaling functions on that one.

Comment: Do you have an example? I don't have an idea how to code it. Thank you.

Comment: Not one that can fit in this comment section, if you now understand your problem is you're doing this on a list of items and you wish to learn how to get a reference to the UI element under the mouse pointer then you should open a new question with as much detail about what you're doing now and what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much！